# savefig loop adds previous plots to figure

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to use a forloop to produce figures for each set of data I have, but while the .show() command produces the correct figure, .savefig() keeps adding the previous plotted values to the new figure. 
In my forloop, this is the relevant sample of the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(X,Y[:,0],'o-')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.savefig('plot'+str(i)+'.png')
```

As a comparison, here is the [savefig plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMZ4V.png) and here is that shown by [show()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVIJn.png). As can be seen, the savefig() plot also plotted the previous result.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to close current figure after saving with function
`plt.close()`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.close

Or you have to clean current figure after saving by `plt.clf()`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf

Comment: plt.clf() did the trick for me! I was goiing mad for more than an hour, your answer saved me.

Comment: This also works when you get blank images while trying to save plots using a `for` loop. Thank you!

Comment: plt.clf() clears the previous plot but retains the figsize, in my case, I used plt.close() as I was plotting two different plots with different fig sizes.

Answer (score 6):

I made some beautiful charts before I included [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#clf) to clear the plot each time through the loop.
[scatterplot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjPpx.png)
[scatterplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7fV4.png)

In other words, my previous plots were being added to a single figure as shown in the lots above, within my for loop as well. adding [`plt.clf()`] to clear the plot each time through the loop fixed this problem being clearing the figure before starting the loop iteration at the top to create a new figure with new plots.

TLDR; I included [`plt.clf()`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#clf) to clear the plot each time through the loop.

Comment: it's not really clear that this relates to the OP's specific question;  please add detail to show how you (1) reproduced the problem and then (2) fixed it with your solution;  the detail should be such that someone else can implement your solution for themselves to verify that it does in fact work;  thx

Comment: just call plt.clf() after each plot has been made and saved in the for loop. Works great. shot !