# matplotlib: sequential plt.savefig problem

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create an animation of plots from a dictionary of integer-arrays. I failed to create a matplotlib.animation directly, thats why I wanted to create the animation from individual images saved to disk.

I use the following code to save the data plots:

```
counter = 0

for k, v in dict.items():
    plt.plot(v)
    filename = str(counter) + ".png"
    plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
    counter = counter + 1
```

where dict is a dictionary of numpy arrays of integers.

The code as such works, but instead of plotting the individual data of each array, the plot/savefig command somehow puts the plota on top of each other, piling up more and more plots. The n-th plot looks like this:

[image]

My problem would be solved if either there is a way to create an animation from the numpy-arrays of ints or if the plots showed only the present array's data.

Comment: A new figure is created via `plt.figure()`. As for the animation, that should be straight forward and there are lots of resources available on how to do it.

Comment: Another relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734512/savefig-loop-adds-previous-plots-to-figure)